# How do I make a button click change the django order_by?

Tags: python, html, django

Here's my views.py function.

```
def publications(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        publications = UserPublications.objects.all().order_by('status_date')
    else:
        publications = UserPublications.objects.all().order_by('contributors')


    context = {'publications': publications}
    return render(request, 'users/publications.html', context)
```

Here's my publications.html:

```
<button type="submit" method="POST">Filter By Date</button>
<ol  class="text">
    {% for publication in publications %}
        <div>{{publication.text}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

I want a button to be clicked on and if someone clicks on it it changes to filter by date instead of by contributors (both attributes of my model). How would I do that? Right now I have no errors but when I click on the button it's not updating the sorting on my objects. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button needs to be linked to a `<form>`, so:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'view-name-for-publications' %}">
    <button type="submit">Filter By Date</button>
</form>
```

It however does not make much sense to use the HTTP request method to determine whether to sort by date or not. Usually, you make a GET request with a [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring) to specify on what field it will sort.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work I tried switching to GET. but whenever I click the button nothing happens still.

Comment: @awawawaw: the `action=""` should link to the view with the `{% url ... %}` template tag.